# Intra-host UDP traffic missing after destination-pod re-created

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

I'm sending UDP packets (statsd) from pods on a host to `<hostIP>:8125`. On the other end, a collector (datadog-agent using `hostPort`; one per host via DaemonSet) picks up the packets and does it's thing.

Generally this works fine, but if I ever delete + re-create the collector (`kubectl delete pod datadog-agent-xxxx`; new pod is started on same IP/port a few seconds later), traffic from *existing* client-sockets stop arriving at the collector (UDP sockets created *after* the pod-rescheduling works fine).

Re-starting just the agent inside the collector pod (`kubectl exec -it datadog-agent-xxxxx agent stop`; auto-restarts after ~30s) the same old traffic *does* show up. So containers somehow must have an impact.

While UDP are (supposedly) stateless, something, somewhere is obviously keeping state around!? Any ideas/pointers?

Each "client" pod has something like this in the deployment/pod:

```
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webservice
          env:
            # Statsd defaults to localhost:8125, but that's this pod. Use `hostPort` on collector + hostIP here to get around that.
            DD_AGENT_HOST:
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: 'status.hostIP'
```

On the collector (following [datadog's k8s docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/daemonset_setup/?tab=k8sfile)):

```
kind: DaemonSet
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: datadog/agent:6.140.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8125
              hostPort: 8125
              protocol: UDP
          env:
            - name: DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC
              value: "true"
            - ...
```

This happens on Kubernetes 1.12 on Google Kubernetes Engine.

Comment: Perhaps the destination IP address is not being updated.

Comment: @Raedwald how so? The traffic flows to the *host* IP, precisely so it will remain constant for the lifetime of the host. My hunch is that somehow, something doesn't get updated correctly somewhere in the container/kernel/network layers. But where?

Comment: What if the new pod has a different IP address from the old pod? If Kubernetes gives each pod a unique IP address, and creates the new pod before disposing of the old pod, the IP address of the new pod *must* be diffrent from the IP address of the old pod.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious here, other than your image tag. It looks like you've got a typo in the Agent tag you're trying to pull? Should be `6.14.0`, not `6.140.0`. Don't know about your `imagePullPolicy` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to this [issue in the portmap plugin](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/issues/123). The current working theory is that a conntrack entry is created when the client pod reaches out for the UDP host port, and that entry becomes stale when the server pod is deleted, but it's not deleted, so clients keep hitting it, essentially blackholing the traffic.

You can try removing the conntrack entry with something like `conntrack -D -p udp --dport 8125` on one of the impacted host. If that solves the issue then that was the root cause of your problem.

This workaround described in the GitHub issue should mitigate the issue until a fix is merged:

You can add an initContainer to the server's pod to run the conntrack command when it starts:

```
initContainers: 
        - image: <conntrack-image>
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
          name: conntrack 
          securityContext: 
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true 
            capabilities: 
              add: ["NET_ADMIN"] 
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'conntrack -D -p udp']
```

Comment: Almost there... But it seems high-traffic applications manage to set up new conntrack-entries between running the initContainer and the datadog-agent starting up. If I log into the node and run the same command *after* the agent has started, everything works fine.

Comment: by `applications manage to set up new conntrack-entries between running the initContainer and the datadog-agent starting up` do you mean that you loose some data before the agent starts, or that you loose **all** data until you run this command yourself after the agent has started? It is normal to loose some points until the agent starts, since statsd works on top of UDP. If the server isn't listening yet the client still sends data. Data should start flowing eventually though.

Comment: Data was still missing after ~five minutes. Clearing the conntrack-table manually or re-starting the sending pod fixes the issue.